No module named 'decouple' when running python manage.py collectstatic in github actions to azure app service
I have a django app that I am deploying via github actions to Azure.
In my workflow file, i have a step for collecting static files but it skips it citing No module named 'decouple' even after adding a specific step prior, to install decouple. I am using poetry for dependency management.
Here is an excerpt to my workflow file
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - {{appname}}

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '20.13'

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: '3.12'

      - name: Cache node modules
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        env:
          cache-name: node-modules-cache
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ steps.vars.outputs.branch }}-${{ steps.vars.outputs.sha_short }}
          restore-keys: |
            build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ steps.vars.outputs.branch }}-${{ steps.vars.outputs.sha_short }}
            build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ steps.vars.outputs.branch }}
            build-${{ env.cache-name }}

      - name: Cache pip
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        env:
          cache-name: pip-cache
        with:
          path: ~/.cache/pip
          key: build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ steps.vars.outputs.branch }}-${{ steps.vars.outputs.sha_short }}
          restore-keys: |
            build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ steps.vars.outputs.branch }}-${{ steps.vars.outputs.sha_short }}
            build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ steps.vars.outputs.branch }}
            build-${{ env.cache-name }}
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          python -m pip install poetry==1.8.3
          curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
          sudo apt-get install git-lfs --upgrade
          poetry install --with dev --no-root --no-interaction --no-ansi
          poetry add python-decouple

      - name: Install dependencies and build static files with webpack
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build
      
      - name: Collect static files
        run: |
          cd backend
          python manage.py collectstatic --noinput 2>&1 | sed '/^Copying/d;/^$/d;/^ /d'

In the server, I am thus unable to run the app as it cannot find the static files. Any help will be appreciated.

Please provide your code.

Please check if the solution below helps you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

Install decouple package using pip install python-decouple.
Or create requirements.txt  file under root directory of DJango app and add the required python packages to install.
requirements.txt:
Django
python-decouple

And add a step pip install -r requirements.txt  to install dependencies in your GitHub workflow:
 - name: Install dependencies
   run: pip install -r requirements.txt

I have created a Django app and used python-decouple:
.env:
DEBUG=True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True
SECRET_KEY=ARANDOMSECRETKEY
DATABASE_URL=mysql://myuser:mypassword@myhost/mydatabase
PERCENTILE=90%
#COMMENTED=42

app=>mysite=>settings.py:
from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config

config.encoding = 'cp1251'
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

Local Response:

Deployed to Azure using GitHub actions:
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - appname

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'appname'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_937EAXXXXE9B }}


